# Allow https on careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, security

At the moment `careers.stackoverflow.com` redirects you if you try and access it using `https`. It would be nice if it allowed secure connections (personally I think it should be the default) given the personal information we are submitting.

I know there is a facility to make the CVs public, but not everyone wants to do that.

Comment: I'd go as far as to suggest https-only. With an EV cert.

Answer (score 12):

I agree. Even if it's not strictly necessary, it's really a sign of professionalism.

Answer (score 3):

We do use https:// for the billing pages on careers.

Comment: This question isn't just about billing.  The entire site should be HTTPS, especially where any PII is being submitted.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Given that PII is being submitted, please could you justify why you are **not** using HTTPS for the entire site? Cost of SSL certificates? Extra CPU load on the servers? You've collected PII from [over 100,000 people](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/about) and all that data was submitted to you unencrypted. I don't think there's any reasonable excuse for that. Apart from the security issues, as Mehrdad says, it's unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that **https should be forced/required**. I believe SE wants to protect their users and customers' PII as trust is critical to their business.

It's subject to MITM modification and snooping at public wifi, employers, and welp, every hop between the user and SE.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a redirect now, https://careers.stackoverflow.com supports HTTPS for logged-in users and redirects to the https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent information site for non-logged in users checking it out.